# "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64" drive persistently showing up in dock

Tags: dock

Recently, a disk called "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS amd64" has been showing up on my dock every time I activate my machine:

[image]

Even if I eject this disk, it reappears after I restart Ubuntu.

I think my machine may have turned off during an update, and since then, this disk has persistently been appearing. This isn't causing any issues at the moment, but the fact that it's there on the dock for no reason at all just bugs me.

Any tips as to how I can get rid of this would be greatly appreciated!

*(I am running Ubuntu 20.04 64-bit on VMWare Workstation 16 Pro.)*

Comment: I don't know vmware, but in virtualbox you can have a dvd/iso inserted via the media settings and it persists through reboots, is there something analogous? It looks like the install media.

Answer (score -1):

How to Remove Mounted Drives From the Left Dock in Ubuntu 21.10, 20.04
https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/11/hide-mounted-drives-left-dock-ubuntu-19-10/

Seems to work better using dConf

Comment: Though this hides the drive, it still exists on the machine ([screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/CrbfzQH.png)). Does that affect anything in any way?